# Python 'KeyError: 0' while printing first column from csv

Tags: python, csv

I'm new in python and trying read each row by column index but getting `KeyError: 0` while executing below code:

```
with open('processed/test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f) 
    for row in reader:
        print row[0]
```

Does any one have idea how to read column by index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you use DictReader, if you want to get row by index? Maybe your code should look like this?

```
with open('processed/test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f) 
    for row in reader:
        print ', '.join(row)
        if len(row):
            print row[0]
```

Comment: hey can you tell me how can i skip first iteration of `reader`

Comment: before reading, you can set i=0 in cycle  do i+=1 if i == 1 continue